Short story where the aliens looks similar to lions can make themselves invisible
On an alien planet, the inhabitants kind of look like lions and can make themselves invisible. The story is told from the point of view of a teenage girl who has one of them as a pet/friend and doesn't realize they are the dominant occupants of this planet. Humans have been hunting them for sport, which was OK with the "lions" because they were also killing some of the humans that were hunting them. But then the humans started using helicopters, and it was no longer a fair fight. There's a scene toward the end where the aliens reveal themselves and many are lined up along the balcony when they become visible.

You could improve this Story-Identification question by going through the checklists here and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

This is one of James Schmitz' Telzey Amberdon stories. "Novice" (first appeared in Analog in 1962).  Reprinted multiple times.
Telzey takes a vacation trip to the resort planet Orado to visit her aunt.  She brings with her a [very large] pet cat Tick-Tock.  Unbeknownst to her, Tick-Tock is really an immature member of a species native to Orado. The adult cats are very large, very fierce, very intelligent, and telepathic. They catalyze Telzey's own latent telepathic abilities and recruit her to restore the balance between cat-hunting humans and human-hunting cats.  Telzey uses her beginning law-student savvy and family political connections to resolve the issue.


Thank you, thank you. For some reason, I want to reread this story and couldn't remember the title or the author. Thanks again.
Carmen
